# Unable to compile C++ function

Tags: c++

My problem might be a petty one, but as a beginner I want to learn the details and hence would be thankful for anyone pointing out my mistakes.

In my header file, I have defined a function like this

```
void  GetFileNames(const fs::path&, const string&, vector<fs::path>&, const bool);
```

Then the function definition goes like this in GetFileNames.cpp  :

```
void GetFileNames(const fs::path& root, const string& ext, vector<fs::path>& names, const bool recursiveflag)
{
        if(!fs::exists(root) || !fs::is_directory(root))
        {
                cout<<"The root path either does not exist, or is not a valid folder.\n"<<endl;
                return;
        }

    if (recursiveflag)
    {
            fs::recursive_directory_iterator it(root);
            fs::recursive_directory_iterator endit;
    }
    else
    {
            fs::directory_iterator it(root);
            fs::directory_iterator endit;
    }

    while(it != endit)
    {
            if(fs::is_regular_file(*it) && it->path().extension() == ext)
                    names.push_back(it->path().filename());

            ++it;
    }
}
```

When I then try to compile program test.cpp where the function has been called in following way like this :

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        vector<fs::path> names;
        fs::path root(argv[1]);
        string ext(argv[2]);
        GetFileNames(root,ext,names,true);
        for(auto i = names.begin(); i!= names.end(); ++i)
                cout<< (*i).string()<<endl;
        return 0;
}
```

I receive the following error :

```
Scanning dependencies of target Test
[ 33%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Test.dir/test.cpp.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Test.dir/GetFileNames.cpp.o
/Users/ujjwalujjwal/prog/src/GetFileNames.cpp:22:8: error: use of undeclared identifier 'it'
        while(it != endit)
              ^
/Users/ujjwalujjwal/prog/src/GetFileNames.cpp:22:14: error: use of undeclared identifier 'endit'
        while(it != endit)
                    ^
/Users/ujjwalujjwal/prog/src/GetFileNames.cpp:24:27: error: use of undeclared identifier 'it'
                if(fs::is_regular_file(*it) && it->path().extension() == ext)
                                        ^
/Users/ujjwalujjwal/prog/src/GetFileNames.cpp:24:34: error: use of undeclared identifier 'it'
                if(fs::is_regular_file(*it) && it->path().extension() == ext)
                                               ^
/Users/ujjwalujjwal/prog/src/GetFileNames.cpp:25:20: error: use of undeclared identifier 'it'
                        names.push_back(it->path().filename());
                                        ^
/Users/ujjwalujjwal/prog/src/GetFileNames.cpp:27:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'it'
                ++it;
                  ^
6 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/Test.dir/GetFileNames.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/Test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I do not seem to understand that where exactly I am making a conceptual error. This seems very trivial, but I would like to understand whats going on here.

Comment: it has nothing to do with bool. your iterators are not in the scope of `while(it != endit)` because you declare them in a if of lower scope.

Comment: Here's an idea. If you think your problem is caused by X, test that hypothesis by removing X from the problem and seeing if it goes away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining the iterators **within** a prior if-else scope:

```
fs::recursive_directory_iterator it(root);
fs::recursive_directory_iterator endit;
```

Therefore when you reference them later in the while loop they no longer exist as the variables are destroyed as soon as your if-else block is finished.

As you have iterators that are of different types depending on the `bool` argument, you might have to actually place the while loop within each of your `if` and `else` blocks to ensure that the iterators still exist when you execute your `while` loop.

However you choose to proceed it is nothing to do with the `boolean` parameter to your function - pay attention to the compiler errors as they are telling you what is wrong.

Comment: Does this mean that I would have to write the same copy of while  in each block of if-else ? Is that the only solution ?

Comment: Thanks I got it. Will take care of these details from now on

Answer (score 1):

`it` is defined in another block, you can't use it in your while loop, unless you define it before

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this bit of code...

```
    ....
    while(it != endit)
    {
        if(fs::is_regular_file(*it) && it->path().extension() == ext)
                names.push_back(it->path().filename());

        ++it;
    }
    ....
```

...is using two variables, 'it' and 'endit'. However in both cases where you declare these are inside {} blocks. This makes the declaration only local to these blocks.

Your problem is made slightly worse by each declaration of 'it' and 'endit' being of different types.

You can either move the declaration outside of the local blocks and make them of some common type (in this case InputIterators) or you can move the while loop at the end inside both local blocks like this...

```
...
    if (recursiveflag)
    {
        fs::recursive_directory_iterator it(root);
        fs::recursive_directory_iterator endit;

        while(it != endit)
        {
            if(fs::is_regular_file(*it) && it->path().extension() == ext)
                    names.push_back(it->path().filename());

            ++it;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        fs::directory_iterator it(root);
        fs::directory_iterator endit;

        while(it != endit)
        {
            if(fs::is_regular_file(*it) && it->path().extension() == ext)
                    names.push_back(it->path().filename());

            ++it;
        }
    }
...
```

Although this leads to unnecessary code duplication and makes for maintenance nightmares further on.